# In Visual Studio 2010, how can I set the default target platform for new projects to x86?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, target, platform

In Visual Studio 2010, how can I set the default target platform for new projects to x86? For some templates, this seems already the case, but for example for Visual Basic Class Library the default is Any Cpu and cannot even be changed.
Where can I centrally define that all projects should target the x86 platform?

Comment: Really good question. I'm getting mad when I add a new project and Visual Studio "kindly" creates several new solution configuration for me because it decides to make the new project as "Any CPU".